# XMPP Connection with server and configure Client side in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, server, xmppframework

I am connecting to the XMPP stream with server but the connection is always successful even if username, password is wrong. Can't understand why this occurs.
I want to configure client side in my app and want to connect my app with the XMPP server. Help will be appreciated. Below is my code:

```
    import UIKit
    import XMPPFramework
    protocol ChatDelegate {
        func buddyWentOnline(name: String)
        func buddyWentOffline(name: String)
        func didDisconnect()
    }
    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, XMPPStreamDelegate, XMPPRosterDelegate{
        var window: UIWindow?
        var delegate:ChatDelegate! = nil
        var xmppStream = XMPPStream()
        let xmppRosterStorage = XMPPRosterCoreDataStorage()
        var xmppRoster: XMPPRoster
        override init() {
            xmppRoster = XMPPRoster(rosterStorage: xmppRosterStorage)
        }
    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:
            [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
                //setupStream()
                self.xmppStream = XMPPStream()
                self.xmppStream.addDelegate(self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
                self.xmppStream.hostName = "****softs-mbp-9"
                self.xmppStream.hostPort = 5222
                self.connect()
                return true
        }
func connect() -> Bool {
            if !xmppStream.isConnected() {
                let jabberID = "admin@****softs-mbp-9"
                let myPassword = "**********"

                if !xmppStream.isDisconnected() {
                    return true
                }
    //            if jabberID == nil && myPassword == nil {
    //                return false
    //            }

                xmppStream.myJID = XMPPJID.jidWithString(jabberID)

                do {
                    try xmppStream.connectWithTimeout(XMPPStreamTimeoutNone)
                    print("Connection success")
                    return true
                } catch {
                    print("Something went wrong!")
                    return false
                }
            } else {
                return true
            }
        }

        func disconnect() {
            goOffline()
            xmppStream.disconnect()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the username to admin@****softs-mbp-9?

Comment: It should be a comment :)

Comment: let jabberID = "admin@****softs-mbp-9" its a username

Comment: however issue resolved. the connection is success with the hostname and port. but the user verification is through user authentication call back.